# Lua missing socket.http module

Tags: haproxy, lua

I am using Lua with HAProxy. I have set `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` as the following:

```
LUA_PATH=/usr/bin/lua;/usr/bin/lua5.3;/usr/share/lua/5.3/ltn12.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/mime.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/ssl.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/posix/_argcheck.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/posix/compat.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/posix/deprecated.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/posix/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/posix/sys.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/posix/util.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/posix/version.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/ftp.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/headers.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/http.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/smtp.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/tp.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/socket/url.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/term/colors.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/term/cursor.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/term/init.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/ssl/https.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/add.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/admin_remove.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/build.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/cache.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/cfg.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/command_line.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/config_cmd.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/deps.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/dir.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/doc.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/download.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fs.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/help.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/index.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/install.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/lint.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/list.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/loader.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/make.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/make_manifest.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/manif_core.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/manif.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/new_version.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/pack.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/path_cmd.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/path.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/persist.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/purge.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/refresh_cache.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/remove.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/repos.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/require.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/search.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/show.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/site_config.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/type_check.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/unpack.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/upload.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/util.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/validate.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/write_rockspec.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/build/builtin.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/build/cmake.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/build/command.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/build/make.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fs/lua.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fs/tools.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fs/unix.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fs/win32.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/cvs.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/git_file.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/git_http.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/git_https.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/git.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/git_ssh.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/hg_http.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/hg_https.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/hg.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/hg_ssh.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/sscm.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/fetch/svn.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/tools/patch.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/tools/tar.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/tools/zip.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/upload/api.lua;/usr/share/lua/5.3/luarocks/upload/multipart.lua
LUA_CPATH=/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/ctype.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/dirent.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/errno.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/fcntl.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/fnmatch.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/glob.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/grp.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/libgen.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/poll.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/pwd.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/sched.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/signal.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/stdio.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/stdlib.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/syslog.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/termio.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/time.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/unistd.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/posix/utime.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/mime/core.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/socket/core.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/socket/serial.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/socket/unix.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/term/core.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/ssl.so;/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/zlib.so
```

My `haproxy.cfg` file tries to load `auth-request.lua` in the `global` section of the file. When I try to start HAProxy, the service fails and doing `journalctl -xe` gives the following error: `module socket.http not found`.

I also installed `luasocket` using `luarocks`.

**EDIT**

I read more about the `require` function in Lua from this [post](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html). The following paragraph was of interest:

`The path used by require is a little different from typical paths. Most programs use paths as a list of directories wherein to search for a given file. However, ANSI C (the abstract platform where Lua runs) does not have the concept of directories. Therefore, the path used by require is a list of patterns, each of them specifying an alternative way to transform a virtual file name (the argument to require) into a real file name. More specifically, each component in the path is a file name containing optional interrogation marks. For each component, require replaces each`?´ `by the virtual file name and checks whether there is a file with that name; if not, it goes to the next component.`

So, following this, I modified my LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH as follows:

`LUA_CPATH="/usr/lib64/lua/5.3/?/?.so"`

`LUA_PATH="/usr/share/lua/5.3/?/?.lua"`

Unfortunately, the error is still there.

Comment: Might want to check versions of lua. Which one is haproxy using and which one is luarocks instaling.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably install luasocket with the distro package manager such as `apt install lua-socket`. This worked for me.